Looking for an answer
I've seen a difficult puzzle published in an old book. It was a prize competition so the answer was not given. I don't know the answer, but I want to.  Is it allowed to post it here in hopes that someone can figure it out?
Entry date expired in 1982. I don't know if the solution was ever published.

Yes, this question could be posted on Puzzling, since the expiry date for the contest has passed. Only questions from ongoing contests (i.e. ones for which a prize is still available  for a correct answer) would fall foul of site policy.
I recommend still stating the source and context fully in the question post - this ensures the puzzle is properly attributed and reinforces the fact that the contest closing date has passed.

And there isn't a problem with posting a puzzle when I don't know the answer?

@Pete I guess that depends on the puzzle. A riddle where you don't know the answer might not be very well received, since it will likely be possible to come up with a dozen potential solutions but no way of confirming which was the author's intent. However, something like a crossword or a logic puzzle should end up having a neatly fitting solution where you know you've reached the solved state.
